# Set TextView to the string for decibel strength - Android Studio

Tags: android, variables, textview, set

***Problem:***

- Setting textView with id of "readOut" to the value testing for wifi signal strength

***Code:***

```
class wifi {
    int signalStrength = 0;
    int loopToggle = 0;
    Context context = MainActivity.this;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    public void loop() throws InterruptedException {
        while (loopToggle == 0) {
            WifiManager signalStrength = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            String wifiInfo = WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_INFO;
            TextView textView = (TextView) textView.findViewById(readOut);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

***Layout File:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.wifilocator.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/readOut"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="filler"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

***Thanks for any help you can provide!***

Comment: "Setting textView with id of "readOut" to the value testing for wifi signal strength" - Why is this a problem? What did you try?

Comment: I tried setting the textView in line 33. It says it "cannot resolve the symbol" when I try to make it target readOut (that is the name of the textView)

Comment: Sorry but there are no line numbers in the code you posted

Comment: Please share the layout file as well

Comment: So sorry. New to this. It would be the line in the while loop starting with "TextView"

Comment: Just added the layout file :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write `R.id.readOut` if you refer to a `View` with the xml attribute `android:id="@+id/readOut"`

So the whole line should be

```
TextView textView = (TextView) textView.findViewById(R.id.readOut);
```

The *R* stands for the [R](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.html) class which will be generated to contain all kinds of resources you need in your app.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll give this a try. I would upvote... but I'm such a noob I don't even have the ranking for it. Thanks for helping the noob! Karma thanks you

Comment: Well, you can accept the answer (grey checkmark) if it works. And we all  started as noobs, so just pay it forward: help others if you can :)

Comment: Just checked it as it worked! :D Thanks a ton. And I will pay it forward, we build each other as a community I suppose :)